# Using the replacement of RSocketFactory

Tags: java, spring, lombok, rsocket

I have been looking through a few RSocket demos and examples to see how they work but most of them tend to have outdated pieces of code.

For example, I have got this demo, with uses RSocketFactory when happens to be deprecated.

```
@Bean
RSocket rSocket () {
    return RSocketFactory
            .connect()
            .dataMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
            .transport(TcpClientTransport.create(7000))
            .start()
            .block();
}
```

I found out through searching more that it was replaced by `RSocketConnectorConfigurer` but I wasn't able to find example code of the new usage. Any chance someone that has played around with RSocket before could help with using the new method for configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: checkout https://github.com/benwilcock/spring-rsocket-demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also facing similar issue due to the api changes. You can use this example.

Check here for more info - http://www.vinsguru.com/rsocket-integrating-with-spring-boot/

```
@Configuration
public class RSocketConfig {

    @Bean
    public RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies() {
        return RSocketStrategies.builder()
                .encoders(encoders -> encoders.add(new Jackson2CborEncoder()))
                .decoders(decoders -> decoders.add(new Jackson2CborDecoder()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Mono<RSocketRequester> getRSocketRequester(RSocketRequester.Builder builder){
        return builder
                .rsocketConnector(rSocketConnector -> rSocketConnector.reconnect(Retry.fixedDelay(2, Duration.ofSeconds(2))))
                .dataMimeType(MediaType.APPLICATION_CBOR)
                .connect(TcpClientTransport.create(6565));
    }

}
```